# Which of these two codes are 'better'? Making a local variable or a class variable?

Tags: unity, c#, game-loop

Im making more games and asking more stupid questions.

Hopefully this one is very brief. I'm making a very basic class which just moves a Player object by applying force to a rigidbody, but it got me wondering, should I be making a class reference to the rb or just a local variable inside Update every frame? (bearing in mind it already exists in the Monobehaviour.GameObject unity parent class).

I'm wondering if doing many local variables would slow down the loop as a whole(by local I mean inside the function itself and not at the top of the class - hope im using the correct term) .

Here is what I mean, the two ways I was thinking of doing it:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    rb.AddForce(v * rb.transform.forward * Const.walkForce);
}
}
```

or...

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
Rigidbody rb;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    rb.AddForce(v * rb.transform.forward * Const.walkForce);
}
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a question for code review SE.

Comment: You could also make float v a class property.

Comment: I probably will in the end actually Chad, because I will use it in two methods within the class. It was really just simple code to get the question about local vs class variables across without bloating it out with lots of code. I'm really liking keeping the variables local (and 'out of the way' as it where!) but of course I must make sure I dont start duplicating things instead of having one class variable for each.

Comment: A snippet of code is not 'a code'. Asking about 'which code is better' makes you look like an amateur.

Comment: i am an amateur so thats fine with me thanks Miles

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general, I've found that you should scope data as narrowly as possible to start with and broaden the scope as you discover you need to. That means if you *can* make it a local variable instead of a member, you should probably start there.

This is because a narrower scope reduces the number of places in the code where you must reason about that data, and thus reduces the number of places you can reason about it incorrectly (which leads to bugs).

Actually *declaring* local variables alone is never going to practically be a performance concern: they're cheap, and modern compilers may even optimize "extras" out.

Initializing them may be a concern; in your case your rigid body is looked up every time via `GetComponent`, which has some non-zero cost. If you know that the rigid body component will *not change* for this particular game object, you can look it up once and store the result in a member variable and avoid a small bit of per-call overhead.

It's unlikely that per-call overhead is going to be significant in this one instance, but over time doing this for many components may add up. You'd want to apply a profiler to be sure.

So, to summarize: in general, default to making things as local as possible, but in this case it's probably reasonable to make `rb` a member so you can perform the lookup once in `Awake` and avoid having to do it every `FixedUpdate` call.

Comment: thank you Josh, I did feel it would be better having the rb initialized just once , and thanks very much for clearly explaining why. It's nice to know for sure, you see i wasnt 100% sure that the GetComponent counted as initializing it each time, or simply 'looking it up' from the Monobehaviour. But now I get it so many thanks for the super-quick helpful answer

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro `GetComponent` *is* pretty fast - you'd be hard pressed making any kind of lookup that has comparable speed. Unless you have performance data that suggests it's a problem, stick with the "keep things local" approach. You can always optimize it later. See https://answers.unity.com/questions/185164/what-more-should-i-be-caching-within-my-scripts.html Don't forget that caching isn't free either - if you cache every single `GetComponent` in your game, it'll *probably* be a net loss. Measure. Identify where optimizations are worth it. Focus on making a great game :)

Comment: The main gist you should take away from this answer (which is pretty good) is: If you want to go for code that is most easy to reason about, to test and to ensure that it is bug-free, take the local variable. But, as always, we sometimes need to make sacrifices to *perfect* code for performance reasons, so a class member might be appropriate (but profile first, don#t simply do premature optimization).

Comment: thanks very much guys, especially Luaan as I was wondering about that 'caching' issue whilst i wrote the original question (but i didn't really know how to word that). I will certainly take the 'local' approach as much as possible. thanks for all the great help as usual fellas.

Answer (score 2):

Josh Petrie's answer is very good - here's a complementary perspective.

When you work with code which you understand the domain of fairly well, you can scope variables to where they make sense.

For instance if I have a `Person` class with a `waveGoodbye` method, it's possible that my class didn't have a `hand` object before and so I could declare it locally in `waveGoodbye`.  Now here it's obvious a person has a hand so you might naturally declare it as a member of `Person` without thinking about it, but the same issue applies.

If you declare `hand` locally then later you might add a `karateChop` method which also requires a hand.  This is when declaring variables locally can become problematic - because junior developers often fall back to copy/pasting the declaration from `waveGoodbye` and now you have the same concept located in two spots.  Any changes to `hand` then need to be modified in both places and thus begins a <s>ant</s> bug hill.

So all in all,

1. If you're confident in the placement of your declaration, scope it to where it makes sense to.
2. If you're not confident, then start local and make sure to refactor when you get a whiff of code reuse.

Edit:
Oh and don't make the same mistake I have of spending too much time figuring out where to scope your declarations.  It's difficult to understand the structure of your data up front, and as you write your code the structure has a way of revealing itself.

Comment: Also having things naturally ordered, like every `Person` should have the member `hand` **if its relevant** in the application, often helps other developers (most times **you** 6 months later) to better understand the code. In this case, it seems logic to have a `Rigidbody` as member of your `Player` and, I say more, even if that implies worse performance. **In video-games** that is a relevant point to consider, but I think **in code**, to be clear is often more important

Comment: excellent answers thanks guys. I'm not trying to sound like an know-all, but tbh all these answers have just re-affirmed what I was thinking already, so for once I'm very happy and making some nice progress in my games. Right now I am making a 3d football game with proper animations and everything, making real strides :D soon I will be here needing help about how to make it 2-player and dare i say online mulitplayer :D have fun guys and thanks again!